# Preload function without context=module script tag

Tags: javascript, preload, svelte, sapper, svelte-3

Since I disliked two script tags in single JS. I shifted `preload()` function in `<script>` without `context=module`. It's working fine. I want to know the wrongs that comes with it.

Comment: `type="module"` allows you to use import statements in the script. As far as I know, that's the only difference; if you need to import stuff, you must keep it, if you don't need to import anything, you can remove it just fine.

Comment: It is not static. More here: https://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html#static-module-structure

Answer (score 1):

The `context=module` script tag allows you to define an "instance" of sorts for the component. There are three main reasons you'd use it that I can see:

1. You can define functions or other code that other components can import. This might usually be better off put in a separate JS/TS file, but hey, sometimes it does make sense.
2. You can define state that should be defined only once for all instances of that component. For example, you could create a counter component that updates all other instances with the same value. **NOTE** It's much better to use a store for this functionality..
3. You can define logic that should happen only once per component, and technically can be used before the component is created. (This somewhat mixes with point #1).

I would assume that moving the `preload` function out of the module script tag does not allow the preloading to happen BEFORE the page component is generated. So essentially, the component is created and the preload function is called, which causes a re-render after the data comes back. If preload were in the module script tag, it is fetched in order to create the first render.

This is my own educated speculation, not necessarily fact.

See the docs [here](https://svelte.dev/docs#script_context_module).